# Can vb6 dll use a .net com visable dll that is in the gac

Tags: .net, dll, com, vb6, com-interop

I have a .Net COM visible dll and a VB6 dll. I registered the .Net dll on the GAC and registered the VB6 dll. My question is can the VB6 dll reference the .Net dll that's in the GAC. If yes, how can this be done? Normally I would use the `regasm` on the .Net dll and everything would be fine but now the .Net dll is in the GAC so I don't think this method would be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything special about it that would stop this from working if you used the GAC or try to use it from a VB6 DLL project.  If you want to write early bound code (actual type names, auto-completion works) then the VB6 IDE needs a type library.  They are normally embedded inside the DLL but that's not the case for .NET [ComVisible] assemblies.

Create a type library with Tlbexp.exe or with Regasm.exe's /tlb command line option.  Like:

```
 regasm foo.dll /tlb:foo.tlb
```

You can now use the type library in your VB6 project.  In the VB6 IDE, use Project + References, click Browse and navigate to the foo.tlb file.

Also note that while the GAC is a good way to avoid DLL Hell, you typically don't use it on your dev machine since it pollutes the machine's GAC.  Use the Regasm /codebase option to have it registered in the directory the DLL is stored in, no need for the GAC then.  You do get a warning from Regasm when you do this, trying to remind you that you are risking DLL Hell.  But that's a problem for your user, not for you.  So you can safely ignore the warning.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but the method depends on how you are deploying your .Net DLL.

If you do it by script, you could do like this:

1. copy your dll to a folder, say c:\program files\myproduct\mydll.dll
2. use regasm to register your dll for com interop
3. use gacutil to put in into GAC

If you use Visual Studio install project:
1. Add the Global Assemly Cache special folder to the project
2. Set the destination folder of the dll to be GAC
3. Set the Register property to vsdraCOM

If you are having trouble adding reference to your .Net DLL from VB6, create a .tlb file from your .Net dll using tlbexp and add a reference to the type library.

This is a link to a more detailed description of the process:  http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/build-and-deploy-a-.net-com-assembly/